# How to handle amazon MWS throttling in Salesforce

Tags: apex, amazon

I am using Amazon MWS to get Orders and insert into Salesforce. Amazon MWS have "maximum request quota"  i.e. It will allow a maximum of 6 Http Callouts. Then after 6 minutes only, we can call another 6 Http Callouts. Is there any way to delay execution for 6 minutes in APEX CODE. Also how to handle this type of Throttling.

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce apex doesn't have a sleep/wait functionality. And it is not planning to have one. The idea is here: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Bq2HAAS

I guess the best you can do here is add it as a schedulable job and schedule it to run every 6 minutes.